# How did the word "humor", which originally represented bodily fluids, end up representing funny things?

Tags: etymology, nouns

The etymology of *humor* shows it represented bodily fluids. It is understood that there was a belief in the ancient time, when each type of bodily fluids were attributed to particular state of mind. But it is not clear how it ended up representing something funny.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=humor

Comment: Well I did look there before posting here, but the connection is still not clear. Thought someone got more to add to it.

Comment: Probably it was from the phrase _(in) (a) good humour_, which came to simply assume _good_, much as _style_ or _taste_ have default assumptions of **good** _style_ or _taste_.

Comment: @Benny: If you looked there before asking here, it's usually a good idea to mention that specifically in your question, along with a link, or some pasted text in a quote box. (Otherwise, we don't know you've seen that, so it's harder to realize that you're looking for something "more.")

Comment: Why close? Do you know the answer? Heh?!

Comment: J.R, I realized that yesterday. Will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the *humors* theory of physiology, both mental and physical health are dependent on a balance of the four primary humors: bile, black bile, phlegm  and blood. A person who has an excess of one humor and a deficiency of the others is out of balance  and is accordingly spoken of (still) as being *out of temper* (Latin *temperare*, 'mix') or as having a *melancholy, bilious, phlegmatic or sanguine temperament*.

*Humor* thus came to be a synonym for imbalance or eccentricity of character, the stock-in-trade of intellectual Renaissance comedy. Ben Jonson for instance wrote a popular play, *Every Man In His Humour*, and a sequel, *Every Man Out of His Humour*; the prologue of the latter defines the comic treatment:

> Some one peculiar quality
>   Doth so possess a man, that it doth draw
>   All his affects, his spirits, and his powers,
>   In their confluctions, all to run one way.

Over the next century, *humor* passed by degrees from signifying what makes a character ridiculous to anything which excites more or less sympathetic laughter.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Provided more information than I hoped for. It is amazing how meanings change over time, particularly getting influenced by imagination of artists of the time (poets in those days, writers and comedians in this age along with poets of course)

Comment: *Humor* was a chic buzzword in Jonson's day: he heaps scorn on the dandies who liked to characterize their fantastic mannerisms of dress and behavior as *humors*.